# Main Window content appearing on page when navigating in GUI using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created simple UI using XAML file. Where I used frame inside grid for navigation. I am setting the content of frame to page when button is click on main window

The XAML file for main window is as below

```
<Window x:Class="ADCP.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ADCP"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ADCP" Height="350" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="31*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="303*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image Height="20" Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="resources/testIcon.jpg" Width="149"/>
        <Image Height="30" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="resources/Logo.png" Margin="344,0,0,0" Width="56"/>
        <Label Content="PROJECT" Grid.Row="1" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="30" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="288,68,0,0" Width="224"></Label>
        <Button x:Name="BtnStart" Click="BtnStart_Click" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="20" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="START" Margin="174,154,0,0" Height="31" Width="61" />
        <Frame Name="MainWindowFrame" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The XAML file for the page is

```
<Page x:Class="ADCP.pages.Page1"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ADCP.pages"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
      Title="Page1">

    <Grid>
        <Button BorderBrush="DarkOrange" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">Help!!</Button>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The codebehind  file to achieve this is as below

```
namespace ADCP
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public Page1 homePage;

        public Page2 helpPage;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            homePage = new Page1(); 
            helpPage = new Page2();
        }

        private void BtnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindowFrame.Content = homePage;
        }
    }
}
```

When I am pressing the button, the information on the page is getting displayed on the main window. I want to achieve that the page should get displayed on whole frame and content of main window in row 1 of grid should not be visible when page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, you have a window with a 2x2 grid where the first row contains two images and the second row contains a label and a button when it first loads. When you click the button, the Page is displayed along with the first row, but you want it to replace both rows i.e. no longer display the first row?

I might be off here though :)

Comment: I want the first row should be displayed since frame I am using for displaying the pages is added to second row in grid. So, only content in second row (i.e., button and label from main window) in second should not be displayed. But currently it is displaying   both the elements